# Angular ng-model $parsers/$formatters are not dynamically changed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, format, angular-ngmodel

I have a directive that take the `ng-model` value and convert the value to mm/inch unit depend on `scope.unit` **that can change by the user selection**

I prefer to use  ngModel.$formatters  ngModel.$parsers rather than chnage the value in the controller, because this change is view only (and actually the real value in controller is 0.1mm unit)

This is the directive:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('mainModule').directive("unitConverter", function () {

        return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: {
                unit: '@'
            },
            require: "ngModel",
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {//1-mm //0-inch

                ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {

                    if (parseInt(scope.unit) === 1) {
                        return (value * 10)
                    }
                    else {
                        return ((parseFloat(value) * 10) * 25.4);
                    }
                });
                ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {

                    if (parseInt(scope.unit) === 1) {
                        return parseFloat(value) / parseFloat(10)
                    }
                    else {
                        return ((parseFloat(value) / parseFloat(10)) / parseFloat(25.4));
                    }

                });
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

It's working fine, but when the user change the unit value (bind to `scope.unit`)  the 
formatters/parsers are not running again, and actually it's remain with the first `scope.unit` value.

**My question:** how can I force angular to take the updated `scope.unit` value and update the view.

Comment: something like this, should work:scope.$watch('unit', () => {
  ngModel.$viewValue = ngModel.$formatters.reduceRight((prev, fn) => fn(prev)), ngModel.$modelValue)
  ngModel.$render()
})

Comment: Not working because angular material also push a function to the formatters

Comment: 'not working' is nice phrase, as well as angular material that was not mentioned in question...

Comment: I ment it's not a generic solution for the problem it's may depend on things outside the project like angular material (and tomorrow  maybe on another)